# Sizing polymer-dialog and polymer-dialog-scrollable: variable height

Tags: javascript, css, polymer

I've just started working with the `polymer-dialog` and `polymer-dialog-scrollable` elements. Using the standard case, and following the examples on the Polymer website, the elements are displaying well.

However, I am running into an issue. The content that I wish to display in the `polymer-dialog-scrollable` does not look good in the standard size dialog:

[image]

I would like to increase the height of the entire dialog box, so I tried styling the elements with CSS:

```
paper-dialog {
    height: 90%;
}
paper-dialog-scrollable {
    height: calc(100% - 128px); /* 128 seemed to account for the header and footer */
}
```

In simple HTML, this should work. But in practice, there is actually a generated `div` inside of the `paper-dialog-scrollable` with id and class `scrollable`, which I assume Polymer is inserting. Inspecting this element, I see this CSS:

```
element.style {
  box-styling: border-box;
  max-height: 60px;
  max-width: 1292.81px;
}
```

Which renders the screen this way:

[image]

I'm not sure where this `max-height: 60px` styling is coming from, or how to overwrite it. Since the `div` seems to be a Polymer-generated object, I assume that this is generated by Polymer at some point. But it's not growing with the rest of the dialog.

**Is there some setting or method for this element that makes sure the inner "scrollable" `div` will grow with its container (`paper-dialog-scrollable`)?**

(Ideally, I would like the dialog to only grow based on the size of the content, with a maximum height of 100%. But that's beyond the scope of this question.)

**UPDATE:**

The max-height is not necessarily sticking on 60px. Right now, it starts at 383px (far below the height of the `paper-dialog-scrollable` element). The height of the "scrollable" `div` does change when I expand and shrink the window, but it always seems like a certain percentage of what it should be.

Here is a code sample of how I'm using the elements inside the HTML body:

```
<body unresolved>
<template is="dom-bind">

<div class="centerPanel">
...
    <paper-button class="jobButton" onclick="openTheDialog('#BADialog')" style="margin-top:50px;">Business Analyst</paper-button>
...
</div>

<paper-dialog id="BADialog" modal>
    <h2>Business Analyst</h2>
    <paper-dialog-scrollable>
        <div class="content" id="BAContent">
            ...
        </div>
    </paper-dialog-scrollable>
    <div class="buttons">
        <paper-button dialog-dismiss>Cancel</paper-button>
        <paper-button dialog-confirm autofocus>Apply for a Business Analyst position</paper-button>
    </div>
</paper-dialog>

</template>

<script>
function openTheDialog(selector) {
    document.querySelector(selector).open();
}
...
</script>


</body>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior in [codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/YWXzyP?editors=1000). The `.scrollable`'s `max-height` grows with its container, as can be seen by resizing the window. Can you update the question to show how you're using `paper-dialog` and `paper-dialog-scrollable`?

Comment: @tony19 I added a code sample and some additional information.

Comment: Hmm. Still works in this [codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/ZOGYEg?editors=1000). What's your CSS look like? And can you show the contents of `div.content`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to @tony19 for the help. I tried his working examples in my environment, and they did not work with the same behavior as on Codepen.

This led me to conclude, rightly, that **it was my environment that was at fault**. I upgraded my local Polymer components to the latest version, and everything now works fine.